# A question about python's JSON/dict conversion

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm using a jsondiff library which returns the following result:

```
a = {'TIERS': {delete: ['APP']}}
```

i'm at a loss as to how this is a valid representation of a dict (or JSON for that matter)? shouldnt this fail because `delete` is not in quotes? however, this seems to come out as a valid dictionary.

this is the full library file: [https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff/blob/master/jsondiff/**init**.py](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff/blob/master/jsondiff/__init__.py)

the relevant parts of the library(atleast from what i can gather):

```
    def emit_dict_diff(self, a, b, s, added, changed, removed):
        if s == 0.0:
            return b
        elif s == 1.0:
            return {}
        else:
            d = {}
            if added:
                d[insert] = added
            if changed:
                d[update] = changed
            if removed:
                d[delete] = list(removed.keys())
```

when i use the dump (json.dump output) option for this library the result is:

```
a = '{"TIERS": {"$delete": ["APP"]}}'
```

i can't find anything on this type of syntax and realize this might be googlable, so sorry if this question comes across as lazy.

edit:

- python 3.6+
- jsondiff library is used as `a=jsondiff.diff(json1,json2,load=True)`

Comment: Maybe, delete is a variable with some value?

Comment: `dict` objects can contain any arbitrary python object as a value, which can implement any representation it wants when it is printed. So it could certainly be a valid python `dict`, however, `delete` is not a `str` object.

Comment: `delete` was a key in this instance, not a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 6 in `jsondiff.__init__.py` file:

```
from .symbols import *
```

Note that it is not advisable to import an entire module using the splat symbol, as it makes the code much harder to read amongst other reasons.

Within `.symbols`, `delete` is defined on line 14:

```
delete = Symbol('delete')
```

and the `Symbol` class itself is defined on line 2 in the same module.

```
class Symbol(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label

    def __str__(self):
        return "$" + self.label
```

If you were to create a dictionary with a variable, e.g. `b`, it would look something like this:

```
b = 'two'
d = {'one': 1, b: 2}
>>> d
{'one': 1, 'two': 2}
```

If you were to use a simple class, however, it would then look like this:

```
class Sym(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

b = Sym('test')
d = {'one': 1, b: 2}
>>> d
{<__main__.Sym at 0x1a194be240>: 2, 'one': 1}
```

Adding a `__repr__` dunder method will make this more readable:

```
class Sym(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label

b = Sym('test')
d = {'one': 1, b: 2}
>>> d
{'one': 1, test: 2}
```

And the final `__str__` method prepends the label with a dollar symbol when converted to a string (e.g. when printed).

```
class Sym(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.label

    def __str__(self):
        return "$" + self.label

b = Sym('test')
d = {'one': 1, b: 2}
>>> d
{test: 2, 'one': 1}

for key in d.keys():
    print(key)
# Output:
# $test
# one
```

Comment: is this at all useful outside of using objects as keys? i can't imagine a usecase where returning this kind of dictionary is useful as definitions arent retained... (tnx for the clarification tho, i did not realize objects could be used as keys, i always assumed it was strings only)

Comment: 'Useful' is in the eye of the beholder.  I probably wouldn't have implemented it like they did, but maybe there is a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

It's a valid Python dict. `delete` is simply an object defined here:
https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff/blob/master/jsondiff/symbols.py#L14